# Spring autowiring based on service availability

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a need of conditionally creating one of three possible implementations of a service depending upon the environment detected by a Spring application at runtime.  If Service A is available, then I want to create a concrete implementation class that uses Service A as a dependency.  If Service A is not available, then I want to create an implementation using Service B as a dependency.  And so-on.

Classes which depend on the implementation will Autowire the Interface and not care what the underlying Service was that got selected for the particular environment.

My first stab at this was to implement multiple @Bean methods which either return a bean or null, depending on whether the Service is available, and to then have a separate @Configuration class which @Autowire(required=false) the two possible services, conditionally creating the implementation depending on which of the @Autowired fields was not-null.

The problem here is that when required=false, Spring doesn't appear to care whether it waits around for candidates to be constructed; that is to say, the class which tries to pick the implementation might be constructed before one or both of the required=false Beans gets constructed, thus ensuring that one or both might always be null, regardless of whether it may manage to initialize correctly.

It kind of feels like I'm going against the grain at this point, so I'm looking for advice on the "right" way to do this sort of thing, where a whole set of beans might get switched out based on the availability of some outside service or environment.

Profiles don't look like the right answer, because I won't know until after my Service beans try to initialize which implementation I want to choose; I certainly won't know it at the time I create the context.

@Order doesn't achieve the goal either.  Nor does @Conditional and testing on the existence of the bean (because it still might not be constructed yet).  Same problem with FactoryBean- it does no good to check for the existence of beans that might not have been constructed at the time the FactoryBean is asked to create an instance.

What I really need to do is create a Bean based on the availability of other beans, but only AFTER those beans have at least had a chance to try to initialize.

Comment: Can you say a little more about what the three implementations are?

Comment: To give a concrete example, depending on availability, I might have an outside Redis cache, an in-memory clustered Hazelcast cache, or if neither of those are available,  just a dumb local HashMap (the fallback).

Depending on what I have, I will construct a concrete implementation of a Service interface that knows how to get/put against a particular bean provided by whichever service was available.

Comment: So what I might like to do is something like:

if (redis beans) return RedisImpl(redis beans)
else if (hazelcast beans) return HazelImpl(hazelcast beans)
else return DumbHashImpl()

Comment: Thanks Nick. And just to clarify, is the availability of specific beans associated with the environment? For example, are you using DumbHashImpl() purely in dev, RedisImpl in test and HazelImpl in prod?

Comment: The answer is "sort of."  I may not always know ahead of time which implementation is going to be available, because things are moving around somewhat rapidly.  For example, even today if I pushed something to production, because that environment trails the others, it would have to fall back on the HashMap implementation today.  But the QA and Stage environments might have Redis, and I might want to test out Hazelcast on my dev box.

I know it isn't ideal. If I could be certain, I'd just use a Profile.

Comment: I could even foresee a situation where Redis weren't available for some reason or other, but I might still be able to coerce Hazelcast to work... so it's almost an "order of preference based on availability" kind of use case.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Profiles is your friend. You can set the current profile by way of environmental variable, command-line argument, and other methods. You can annotate a Spring-managed component so that it's created for a certain profile.

[Spring Profiles from the Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Comment: Profiles are not the answer when I don't know when my application starts which profile I'm going to need.

Comment: Fair enough, @NickJohnson, but if it helps you can also set a profile programmatically at runtime, at least in Spring Boot.

Comment: Indeed. The problem in this case is a sort of chicken-and-egg one-- I don't know which profile to pick until I've already tried to initialize the beans... which means I needed to already know which profile to pick.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case it turned out to be a tangential mistake that influenced the whole wrong behavior.

To give some background, my first, naive (but workable) approach looked like this:

```
@Autowired(required=false)
@Qualifier(RedisConfig.HISTORY)
private RLocalCachedMap<String, History> redisHistoryMap;

@Autowired(required=false)
@Qualifier(HazelcastConfig.HISTORY)
private IMap<String, History> hazelcastHistoryMap;

// RequestHistory is an interface
@Bean
public RequestHistory requestHistory() {
    if (redisHistoryMap != null) {
        return new RedisClusteredHistory(redisHistoryMap);
    } else if (hazelcastHistoryMap != null) {
        return new HazelcastClusteredHistory(hazelcastHistoryMap);
    } else {
        return new LocalRequestHistory();  // dumb hashmap
    }
}
```

In other `@Configuration` classes, if the beans that get `@Autowired` here aren't available (due to missing configuration, exceptions during initialization, etc), the @Bean methods that create them return null.

The *observed* behavior was that this `@Bean` method was getting called after the `RLocalCachedMap<>` `@Bean` method got called, but *before* Spring attempted to create the `IMap<>` by calling its `@Bean` method.  I had incorrectly thought that this had something to do with `required=false` but in fact that had nothing to do with it.

What actually happened was I accidentally used the same constant for both `@Bean` names (and consequently `@Qualifier`s), so presumably Spring couldn't tell the difference when it was calculating its dependency graph for this `@Configuration` class... because the two `@Autowire`d beans appeared to be the same thing (because they had the same name).

(There's a secondary reason for using `@Qualifier` in this case, which I won't go into here, but suffice it to say it's possible to have many maps of the same type.)

Once I qualified the names better, the code did exactly what I wanted it to, albeit in a way that's somewhat inelegant/ugly.

At some point I'll go back and see if it looks more elegant / less ugly and works just as well to use `@Conditional` and `@Primary` instead of the if/else foulness.

The lesson here is that if you explicitly name beans, make absolutely sure your names are *unique* across your application, even if you plan to swap things around like this.